# About adding cardview programatically inside linear layout

Tags: android, layout

I have to create a case where I need to insert 5 card-like structure, inside my linearlayout present in *activity_main.xml*

activity_main layout is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

</LinearLayout>

And the cardview layout is like this :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Title from Android"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="adding layout dynamically"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="serif"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And on mainactivity onCreate() method I have :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout parent=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewMain);
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_main,parent,true);

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            parent.addView(view,i);  
        }

    }
```

Error shown is like :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.workout/com.example.workout.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
> parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent
> first.
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5377)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5192)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5132)
> at com.example.workout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3704)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

Can anybody please help me how can I fix this , so that I can dynamically insert 5 card like structures inside my linear layout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater(); 
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_main,parent,true);
```

to

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_main, null);
```

and add `LayoutInflater` code in for loop

Add following code in `MainActivity.java`

```
LinearLayout parent=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewMain);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_main, null);
    TextView title =  view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView desc =  view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    parent.addView(view);
}
```